# SharePoint 2013, Cannot Open Documents in Office 2010 or Office 2013

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 Foundation site running on Server 2012.  A few days ago an overzealous consultant changed the security certificate on this server in error.  From that point forward, even after correcting the certificate, Office 2010 and Office 2013 clients have been unable to open documents directly from SharePoint.  Everything appears to function as it should, and there are no errors in the logs, but the client application opens and shows no document.  On Office 2013, after confirming that you want to open the document, it shows to be contacting the server before it opens the full application.  Once the application is open there is just the application with no document.  Office 2007 clients are able to use documents from SharePoint without any major issues, the only difference being that they issue a second login prompt before opening the document.

I have tried every possible fix I was able to locate, without any luck.

Office 2010 with Office 2013 application installed -- N/A
Office 2010 SP2 install -- No change
Specify browser-enabled documents are opened in client application -- No change
Enable security certificate in IIS, SharePoint, and Server Certificate Store -- No change
Added to Trusted Sites -- No change
Added to Intranet Sites -- No change
Tested on Windows 7 with Office 2007 -- working
Tested on Windows 7 with Office 2010 SP1 and SP2 -- Not working
Tested on Windows 8 with Office 2013 -- Not working
Tested on Server 2008 with Office 2010 SP1 -- Not working
Tested on Windows 7 with Office 2010 after doing repair install -- Not working
Tested on Server 2008 with Office 2010 after doing repair install -- Not working

All systems were working before the initial certificate change issue.  Any insight or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,
Cory

Comment: Looks like a call to M$ to me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who happens to find this via search, I have found the answer to the problem.  In Office 2010 and Office 2013 the default authentication is based on using a Client certificate.  What this means is that if the IIS server that SharePoint is running on allows Client certificates, and you don't have one installed that matches the application, Office 2010 and Office 2013 will just hang without prompting for an alternate authentication method.  In order to resolve this issue I had to change the SSL Settings on the SharePoint site to Ignore Client certificates.

IIS Manager -> Server -> Sites -> SharePoint -> SSL Settings -> Client certificates -> Ignore